# Can we convert elf from a cpu architecture to another, in linux?

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, elf

If I am running linux using some cpu architecture (e.g. amd64), can I "convert" some elf built for e.g. aarch64 to run on the host cpu arch? *I know* I can use `qemu`, or other virtualization software like `VirtualBox`. I am just curious about the conversion from a binary CPU assembly instructions in an elf to another assembly, to run it natively ? Is it possible theoritically and/or practically? Has anyone made a software for such task ? What are the constraints of doing that?

Comment: I think it's possible but there is no such a free tool...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation .  Short answer: it's hard.  But Apple's Rosetta2 is a pretty successful example.

Comment: QEMU does on-the-fly (JIT) dynamic translation for some combinations, I think including emulating ARM64 on x86-64.  It doesn't cache the results anywhere between runs, though, so it doesn't spend as much time optimizing as Apple's Rosetta which is integrated into the OS to make that work as transparently as they can.  Another option is to decompile and recompile, if the application is simple enough for that to actually produce a working binary, and you have all necessary libraries.  (I'd guess often not if library data structures are part of the ABI).